# Подскажите аналог метода из Python rjust() для C++

Tags: c++

Подскажите аналог метода из Python `rjust()` для C++.
Мне нужно преобразовать время в секундах в формат `hh:mm:ss`.
В Python для этого я использовал метод `rjust()`, предварительно преобразовав секунды в часы, минуты, секунды:

```
t = hrs.rjust(2, "0") + ":" + min.rjust(2, "0") + ":" + sec.rjust(2, "0")
```

здесь метод `rjust` дополнял нулями слева недостающие позиции.

Возможно в С++ есть метод, который непосредственно это выполнит, без дополнительных преобразований.

Попробовал в таком виде, но секунды представлены только одним разрядом (т.е.
вместо "00:00:02" пишет "00:00:2")

```
  QString hrs = QString::number(h);
  QString min = QString::number(m);
  QString sec = QString::number(s);
  std::ostringstream sstr;
  sstr << hrs.toStdString() << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << ":" << min.toStdString() << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << ":" << sec.toStdString() << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0');
  std::string tm = sstr.str();
  ui_progress->label_remaining->setText(QString::fromStdString(tm));
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_of_day

Answer (score 3):

Спасибо! Получилось так:

```
  std::ostringstream sstr;
  sstr << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << hrs.toStdString() << ":" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << min.toStdString() << ":" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << sec.toStdString();
  std::string tm = sstr.str();
  ui_progress->label_remaining->setText(QString::fromStdString(tm));
```

Answer (score 2):

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

template<class T> std::string rjust(int n, T &&t) {
    return static_cast<std::ostringstream const &>(
        std::ostringstream() << std::setw(n) << std::setfill('0') << t).str();
}
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, пример использования функции

Comment: Через темплейты для меня сложно очень на данном этапе. А можете подсказать как для одной строки будет выглядеть код, например:           std::ostringstream sstr;     sstr << sec.toStdString() << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0'); Попробовал в таком виде, но показывает только один символ.

Comment: я добавил, что у меня получилось

Comment: Ну так правильно, сперва секунды, потом формат. :D Надо ж наоборот: `sstr << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << sec.toStdString()` (интересно, QString не умеет в STLные потоки 0_o).

Answer (score 1):

В прекрасном новом мире делают так: `std::format("{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}", 1, 2, 3)` -> `01:02:03`.

Answer (score 0):

```
QString hrs = QString::number(h).rightJustified(2, '0');
QString min = QString::number(m).rightJustified(2, '0');
QString sec = QString::number(s).rightJustified(2, '0');
```

Comment: Постарайтесь оставлять немного более развернутые ответы. Дополнить вопрос можно, нажав кнопку [edit].